# NumberFormatException error with parsing strings to doubles, from html form! (servlets)

Tags: java, servlets

I'm having an HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error, to be more specific:

```
Type Exception Report

Message For input string: "from"

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "from"
sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:502)
servlets.Servlet2.doGet(Servlet2.java:31)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:686)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

The situation I'm trying to resolve is that I have Servlet1 that has an html form with two numeric inputs, when you sumbit them, they send to Servlet2 that takes those inputs check them through an if statement and then parse the strings to doubles. Then the value between those inputs will be the data that will appear. So, I'm getting an error for NumberFormatException, I don't get it where I'm wrong. In the snippet I'm posting I was trying to workaround the problem with the method valueOf, still same problem.

```
    double douFrom = 0;
    double douTo = 0;
    String from = request.getParameter("from");
    String to = request.getParameter("to");

    boolean val = true;

    if ((from != null) && (to != null) && from.matches(".*[0-9]+.*") && to.matches(".*[0-9]+.*") && (from.length()>0) && (to.length()>0)) {
        douFrom = Double.valueOf("from");
        douTo = Double.valueOf("to");
    } else {
        val = false;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remove the quotes: `Double.valueOf(from)`, not `Double.valueOf("from")`. I mean the error message is pretty explanatory: The 4-letter string value `from` is not a valid number.

Comment: `Double.valueOf("from");`?  How is `"from"` a `double`?, maybe you meant `Double.valueOf(from);`?

Comment: `Double.valueOf(from)` is still broken, because your regex only checks if the string *contains* a number. If you want it to parse only digits, you'll need to use `"[0-9]+"` or `"\\d+"`. But that'll only match integers of course.

Comment: Let me clarify a bit more, so the form I'm talking about has two inputs one that is "from" and the other is "to". The way I must handle this is, if from and to are numbers (althought I'm getting them as strings because of the form) parse them to double and show data between these range, else if the inputs are not numbers show all the data!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
douFrom = Double.valueOf("from");
douTo = Double.valueOf("to");
```

You are parsing string literals, not the variables. It must be this way:

```
douFrom = Double.valueOf(from); //remove the quotes
douTo = Double.valueOf(to);
```

Anyway I think is better to validate if your input is a valid double by catching that excepcion instead of using a regex:

```
try{
    douFrom = Double.valueOf(from);
    douTo = Double.valueOf(to);
}catch(NullPointerException | NumberFormatException ex){
    val = false;
}
```

Comment: I agree  entirely with your last paragraph.

Comment: First of all, thanks, I didn't even get , that inside the quotes it literally parses the word from?! 

So you mean is better to delete the regex, and if it the inputs cannot be parsed, then I will catch that exception and handle the error in the catch section instead of the try section(currently if the forms sends something instead of a double number, the whole data just appears and that is intenional)

Comment: What I mean is that the try-catch block that I have posted does what you do on your if-else statement but simpler and evaluates any possible valid double value.